# jquery slideshow

Tags: mootools, slideshow

I'm using a slideshow script in my site. I'm new to javascript. I want one thing.
When i put the mouse over a slide, it should pause on the picture, and not keep changing.
I'm using mootools.

[Slideshow link](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/)

```
var gallery = {
    initialize: function(element, options) {
        this.setOptions({
            showArrows: true,
            showCarousel: true,
            showInfopane: true,
            embedLinks: true,
            fadeDuration: 500,
            timed: false,
            delay: 5000,
            preloader: true,
            preloaderImage: true,
            preloaderErrorImage: true,
            /* Data retrieval */
            manualData: [],
            populateFrom: false,
            populateData: true,
            destroyAfterPopulate: true,
            elementSelector: "div.imageElement",
            titleSelector: "h3",
            subtitleSelector: "p",
            linkSelector: "a.open",
            imageSelector: "img.full",
            thumbnailSelector: "img.thumbnail",
            defaultTransition: "fade",
            /* InfoPane options */
            slideInfoZoneOpacity: 0.7,
            slideInfoZoneSlide: true,
            /* Carousel options */
            carouselMinimizedOpacity: 0.4,
            carouselMinimizedHeight: 20,
            carouselMaximizedOpacity: 0.9,
            thumbHeight: 75,
            thumbWidth: 100,
            thumbSpacing: 10,
            thumbIdleOpacity: 0.2,
            textShowCarousel: 'Overview',
            showCarouselLabel: true,
            thumbCloseCarousel: false,
            useThumbGenerator: false,
            thumbGenerator: 'resizer.php',
            useExternalCarousel: false,
            carouselElement: false,
            carouselHorizontal: true,
            activateCarouselScroller: true,
            carouselPreloader: true,
            textPreloadingCarousel: 'Loading...',
            /* CSS Classes */
            baseClass: 'jdGallery',
            withArrowsClass: 'withArrows',
            /* Plugins: HistoryManager */
            useHistoryManager: false,
            paused: false,
            customHistoryKey: false
        }, options);
        this.fireEvent('onInit');
        this.currentIter = 0;
        this.lastIter = 0;
        this.maxIter = 0;
        this.galleryElement = element;
        this.galleryData = this.options.manualData;
        this.galleryInit = 1;
        this.galleryElements = Array();
        this.thumbnailElements = Array();
        this.galleryElement.addClass(this.options.baseClass);

        this.populateFrom = element;
        if (this.options.populateFrom)
            this.populateFrom = this.options.populateFrom;      
        if (this.options.populateData)
            this.populateData();
        element.style.display="block";

        if (this.options.useHistoryManager)
            this.initHistory();

        if (this.options.embedLinks)
        {
            this.currentLink = new Element('a').addClass('open').setProperties({
                href: '#',
                title: ''
            }).injectInside(element);
            if ((!this.options.showArrows) && (!this.options.showCarousel))
                this.galleryElement = element = this.currentLink;
            else
                this.currentLink.setStyle('display', 'none');
        }

        this.constructElements();
        if ((this.galleryData.length>1)&&(this.options.showArrows))
        {
            var leftArrow = new Element('a').addClass('left').addEvent(
                'click',
                this.prevItem.bind(this)
            ).injectInside(element);
            var rightArrow = new Element('a').addClass('right').addEvent(
                'click',
                this.nextItem.bind(this)
            ).injectInside(element);
            this.galleryElement.addClass(this.options.withArrowsClass);
        }
        this.loadingElement = new Element('div').addClass('loadingElement').injectInside(element);
        if (this.options.showInfopane) this.initInfoSlideshow();
        if (this.options.showCarousel) this.initCarousel();
        this.doSlideShow(1);
    },
    populateData: function() {
        currentArrayPlace = this.galleryData.length;
        options = this.options;
        var data = $A(this.galleryData);
        data.extend(this.populateGallery(this.populateFrom, currentArrayPlace));
        this.galleryData = data;
        this.fireEvent('onPopulated');
    },
    populateGallery: function(element, startNumber) {
        var data = [];
        options = this.options;
        currentArrayPlace = startNumber;
        element.getElements(options.elementSelector).each(function(el) {
            elementDict = {
                image: el.getElement(options.imageSelector).getProperty('src'),
                number: currentArrayPlace,
                transition: this.options.defaultTransition
            };
            elementDict.extend = $extend;
            if ((options.showInfopane) | (options.showCarousel))
                elementDict.extend({
                    title: el.getElement(options.titleSelector).innerHTML,
                    description: el.getElement(options.subtitleSelector).innerHTML
                });
            if (options.embedLinks)
                elementDict.extend({
                    link: el.getElement(options.linkSelector).href||false,
                    linkTitle: el.getElement(options.linkSelector).title||false,
                    linkTarget: el.getElement(options.linkSelector).getProperty('target')||false
                });
            if ((!options.useThumbGenerator) && (options.showCarousel))
                elementDict.extend({
                    thumbnail: el.getElement(options.thumbnailSelector).getProperty('src')
                });
            else if (options.useThumbGenerator)
                elementDict.extend({
                    thumbnail: options.thumbGenerator + '?imgfile=' + elementDict.image + '&max_width=' + options.thumbWidth + '&max_height=' + options.thumbHeight
                });

            data.extend([elementDict]);
            currentArrayPlace++;
            if (this.options.destroyAfterPopulate)
                el.remove();
        });
        return data;
    },
    constructElements: function() {
        el = this.galleryElement;
        this.maxIter = this.galleryData.length;
        var currentImg;
        for(i=0;i<this.galleryData.length;i++)
        {
            var currentImg = new Fx.Styles(
                new Element('div').addClass('slideElement').setStyles({
                    'position':'absolute',
                    'left':'0px',
                    'right':'0px',
                    'margin':'0px',
                    'padding':'0px',
                    'backgroundPosition':"center center",
                    'opacity':'0'
                }).injectInside(el),
                'opacity',
                {duration: this.options.fadeDuration}
            );
            if (this.options.preloader)
            {
                currentImg.source = this.galleryData[i].image;
                currentImg.loaded = false;
                currentImg.load = function(imageStyle) {
                    if (!imageStyle.loaded) {
                        new Asset.image(imageStyle.source, {
                                    'onload'  : function(img){
                                                    img.element.setStyle(
                                                    'backgroundImage',
                                                    "url('" + img.source + "')")
                                                    img.loaded = true;
                                                }.bind(this, imageStyle)
                        });
                    }
                }.pass(currentImg, this);
            } else {
                currentImg.element.setStyle('backgroundImage',
                                    "url('" + this.galleryData[i].image + "')");
            }
            this.galleryElements[parseInt(i)] = currentImg;
        }
    },
    destroySlideShow: function(element) {
        var myClassName = element.className;
        var newElement = new Element('div').addClass('myClassName');
        element.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, element);
    },
    startSlideShow: function() {
        this.fireEvent('onStart');
        this.loadingElement.style.display = "none";
        this.lastIter = this.maxIter - 1;
        this.currentIter = 0;
        this.galleryInit = 0;
        this.galleryElements[parseInt(this.currentIter)].set({opacity: 1});
        if (this.options.showInfopane)
            this.showInfoSlideShow.delay(1000, this);
        var textShowCarousel = formatString(this.options.textShowCarousel, this.currentIter+1, this.maxIter);
        if (this.options.showCarousel&&(!this.options.carouselPreloader))
            this.carouselBtn.setHTML(textShowCarousel).setProperty('title', textShowCarousel);
        this.prepareTimer();
        if (this.options.embedLinks)
            this.makeLink(this.currentIter);
    },
    nextItem: function() {
        this.fireEvent('onNextCalled');
        this.nextIter = this.currentIter+1;
        if (this.nextIter >= this.maxIter)
            this.nextIter = 0;
        this.galleryInit = 0;
        this.goTo(this.nextIter);
    },
    prevItem: function() {
        this.fireEvent('onPreviousCalled');
        this.nextIter = this.currentIter-1;
        if (this.nextIter <= -1)
            this.nextIter = this.maxIter - 1;
        this.galleryInit = 0;
        this.goTo(this.nextIter);
    },
    goTo: function(num) {
        this.clearTimer();
        if(this.options.preloader)
        {
            this.galleryElements[num].load();
            if (num==0)
                this.galleryElements[this.maxIter - 1].load();
            else
                this.galleryElements[num - 1].load();
            if (num==(this.maxIter - 1))
                this.galleryElements[0].load();
            else
                this.galleryElements[num + 1].load();

        }
        if (this.options.embedLinks)
            this.clearLink();
        if (this.options.showInfopane)
        {
            this.slideInfoZone.clearChain();
            this.hideInfoSlideShow().chain(this.changeItem.pass(num, this));
        } else
            this.currentChangeDelay = this.changeItem.delay(500, this, num);
        if (this.options.embedLinks)
            this.makeLink(num);
        this.prepareTimer();
        /*if (this.options.showCarousel)
            this.clearThumbnailsHighlights();*/
    },
    changeItem: function(num) {
        this.fireEvent('onStartChanging');
        this.galleryInit = 0;
        if (this.currentIter != num)
        {
            for(i=0;i<this.maxIter;i++)
            {
                if ((i != this.currentIter)) this.galleryElements[i].set({opacity: 0});
            }
            gallery.Transitions[this.galleryData[num].transition].pass([
                this.galleryElements[this.currentIter],
                this.galleryElements[num],
                this.currentIter,
                num], this)();
            this.currentIter = num;
        }
        var textShowCarousel = formatString(this.options.textShowCarousel, num+1, this.maxIter);
        if (this.options.showCarousel)
            this.carouselBtn.setHTML(textShowCarousel).setProperty('title', textShowCarousel);
        this.doSlideShow.bind(this)();
        this.fireEvent('onChanged');
    },
    clearTimer: function() {
        if (this.options.timed)
            $clear(this.timer);
    },
    prepareTimer: function() {
        if (this.options.timed)
            this.timer = this.nextItem.delay(this.options.delay, this);
    },
    doSlideShow: function(position) {
        if (this.galleryInit == 1)
        {
            imgPreloader = new Image();
            imgPreloader.onload=function(){
                this.startSlideShow.delay(10, this);
            }.bind(this);
            imgPreloader.src = this.galleryData[0].image;
            if(this.options.preloader)
                this.galleryElements[0].load();
        } else {
            if (this.options.showInfopane)
            {
                if (this.options.showInfopane)
                {
                    this.showInfoSlideShow.delay((500 + this.options.fadeDuration), this);
                } else
                    if ((this.options.showCarousel)&&(this.options.activateCarouselScroller))
                        this.centerCarouselOn(position);
            }
        }
    },
    createCarousel: function() {
        var carouselElement;
        if (!this.options.useExternalCarousel)
        {
            var carouselContainerElement = new Element('div').addClass('carouselContainer').injectInside(this.galleryElement);
            this.carouselContainer = new Fx.Styles(carouselContainerElement, {transition: Fx.Transitions.expoOut});
            this.carouselContainer.normalHeight = carouselContainerElement.offsetHeight;
            this.carouselContainer.set({'opacity': this.options.carouselMinimizedOpacity, 'top': (this.options.carouselMinimizedHeight - this.carouselContainer.normalHeight)});
            this.carouselBtn = new Element('a').addClass('carouselBtn').setProperties({
                title: this.options.textShowCarousel
            }).injectInside(carouselContainerElement);
            if(this.options.carouselPreloader)
                this.carouselBtn.setHTML(this.options.textPreloadingCarousel);
            else
                this.carouselBtn.setHTML(this.options.textShowCarousel);
            this.carouselBtn.addEvent(
                'click',
                function () {
                    this.carouselContainer.clearTimer();
                    this.toggleCarousel();
                }.bind(this)
            );
            this.carouselActive = false;

            carouselElement = new Element('div').addClass('carousel').injectInside(carouselContainerElement);
            this.carousel = new Fx.Styles(carouselElement);
        } else {
            carouselElement = $(this.options.carouselElement).addClass('jdExtCarousel');
        }
        this.carouselElement = new Fx.Styles(carouselElement, {transition: Fx.Transitions.expoOut});
        this.carouselElement.normalHeight = carouselElement.offsetHeight;
        if (this.options.showCarouselLabel)
            this.carouselLabel = new Element('p').addClass('label').injectInside(carouselElement);
        carouselWrapper = new Element('div').addClass('carouselWrapper').injectInside(carouselElement);
        this.carouselWrapper = new Fx.Styles(carouselWrapper, {transition: Fx.Transitions.expoOut});
        this.carouselWrapper.normalHeight = carouselWrapper.offsetHeight;
        this.carouselInner = new Element('div').addClass('carouselInner').injectInside(carouselWrapper);
        if (this.options.activateCarouselScroller)
        {
            this.carouselWrapper.scroller = new Scroller(carouselWrapper, {
                area: 100,
                velocity: 0.2
            })

            this.carouselWrapper.elementScroller = new Fx.Scroll(carouselWrapper, {
                duration: 400,
                onStart: this.carouselWrapper.scroller.stop.bind(this.carouselWrapper.scroller),
                onComplete: this.carouselWrapper.scroller.start.bind(this.carouselWrapper.scroller)
            });
        }
    },
    fillCarousel: function() {
        this.constructThumbnails();
        this.carouselInner.normalWidth = ((this.maxIter * (this.options.thumbWidth + this.options.thumbSpacing + 2))+this.options.thumbSpacing) + "px";
        this.carouselInner.style.width = this.carouselInner.normalWidth;
    },
    initCarousel: function () {
        this.createCarousel();
        this.fillCarousel();
        if (this.options.carouselPreloader)
            this.preloadThumbnails();
    },
    flushCarousel: function() {
        this.thumbnailElements.each(function(myFx) {
            myFx.element.remove();
            myFx = myFx.element = null;
        });
        this.thumbnailElements = [];
    },
    toggleCarousel: function() {
        if (this.carouselActive)
            this.hideCarousel();
        else
            this.showCarousel();
    },
    showCarousel: function () {
        this.fireEvent('onShowCarousel');
        this.carouselContainer.start({
            'opacity': this.options.carouselMaximizedOpacity,
            'top': 0
        }).chain(function() {
            this.carouselActive = true;
            this.carouselWrapper.scroller.start();
            this.fireEvent('onCarouselShown');
            this.carouselContainer.options.onComplete = null;
        }.bind(this));
    },
    hideCarousel: function () {
        this.fireEvent('onHideCarousel');
        var targetTop = this.options.carouselMinimizedHeight - this.carouselContainer.normalHeight;
        this.carouselContainer.start({
            'opacity': this.options.carouselMinimizedOpacity,
            'top': targetTop
        }).chain(function() {
            this.carouselActive = false;
            this.carouselWrapper.scroller.stop();
            this.fireEvent('onCarouselHidden');
            this.carouselContainer.options.onComplete = null;
        }.bind(this));
    },
    constructThumbnails: function () {
        element = this.carouselInner;
        for(i=0;i<this.galleryData.length;i++)
        {
            var currentImg = new Fx.Style(new Element ('div').addClass("thumbnail").setStyles({
                    backgroundImage: "url('" + this.galleryData[i].thumbnail + "')",
                    backgroundPosition: "center center",
                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                    marginLeft: this.options.thumbSpacing + "px",
                    width: this.options.thumbWidth + "px",
                    height: this.options.thumbHeight + "px"
                }).injectInside(element), "opacity", {duration: 200}).set(this.options.thumbIdleOpacity);
            currentImg.element.addEvents({
                'mouseover': function (myself) {
                    myself.clearTimer();
                    myself.start(0.99);
                    if (this.options.showCarouselLabel)
                        $(this.carouselLabel).setHTML('<span class="number">' + (myself.relatedImage.number + 1) + "/" + this.maxIter + ":</span> " + myself.relatedImage.title);
                }.pass(currentImg, this),
                'mouseout': function (myself) {
                    myself.clearTimer();
                    myself.start(this.options.thumbIdleOpacity);
                }.pass(currentImg, this),
                'click': function (myself) {
                    this.goTo(myself.relatedImage.number);
                    if (this.options.thumbCloseCarousel)
                        this.hideCarousel();
                }.pass(currentImg, this)
            });

            currentImg.relatedImage = this.galleryData[i];
            this.thumbnailElements[parseInt(i)] = currentImg;
        }
    },
    log: function(value) {
        if(console.log)
            console.log(value);
    },
    preloadThumbnails: function() {
        var thumbnails = [];
        for(i=0;i<this.galleryData.length;i++)
        {
            thumbnails[parseInt(i)] = this.galleryData[i].thumbnail;
        }
        this.thumbnailPreloader = new Preloader();
        this.thumbnailPreloader.addEvent('onComplete', function() {
            var textShowCarousel = formatString(this.options.textShowCarousel, this.currentIter+1, this.maxIter);
            this.carouselBtn.setHTML(textShowCarousel).setProperty('title', textShowCarousel);
        }.bind(this));
        this.thumbnailPreloader.load(thumbnails);
    },
    clearThumbnailsHighlights: function()
    {
        for(i=0;i<this.galleryData.length;i++)
        {
            this.thumbnailElements[i].clearTimer();
            this.thumbnailElements[i].start(0.2);
        }
    },
    changeThumbnailsSize: function(width, height)
    {
        for(i=0;i<this.galleryData.length;i++)
        {
            this.thumbnailElements[i].clearTimer();
            this.thumbnailElements[i].element.setStyles({
                'width': width + "px",
                'height': height + "px"
            });
        }
    },
    centerCarouselOn: function(num) {
        if (!this.carouselWallMode)
        {
            var carouselElement = this.thumbnailElements[num];
            var position = carouselElement.element.offsetLeft + (carouselElement.element.offsetWidth / 2);
            var carouselWidth = this.carouselWrapper.element.offsetWidth;
            var carouselInnerWidth = this.carouselInner.offsetWidth;
            var diffWidth = carouselWidth / 2;
            var scrollPos = position-diffWidth;
            this.carouselWrapper.elementScroller.scrollTo(scrollPos,0);
        }
    },
    initInfoSlideshow: function() {
        /*if (this.slideInfoZone.element)
            this.slideInfoZone.element.remove();*/
        this.slideInfoZone = new Fx.Styles(new Element('div').addClass('slideInfoZone').injectInside($(this.galleryElement))).set({'opacity':0});
        var slideInfoZoneTitle = new Element('h2').injectInside(this.slideInfoZone.element);
        var slideInfoZoneDescription = new Element('p').injectInside(this.slideInfoZone.element);
        this.slideInfoZone.normalHeight = this.slideInfoZone.element.offsetHeight;
        this.slideInfoZone.element.setStyle('opacity',0);
    },
    changeInfoSlideShow: function()
    {
        this.hideInfoSlideShow.delay(10, this);
        this.showInfoSlideShow.delay(500, this);
    },
    showInfoSlideShow: function() {
        this.fireEvent('onShowInfopane');
        this.slideInfoZone.clearTimer();
        element = this.slideInfoZone.element;
        element.getElement('h2').setHTML(this.galleryData[this.currentIter].title);
        element.getElement('p').setHTML(this.galleryData[this.currentIter].description);
        if(this.options.slideInfoZoneSlide)
            this.slideInfoZone.start({'opacity': [0, this.options.slideInfoZoneOpacity], 'height': [0, this.slideInfoZone.normalHeight]});
        else
            this.slideInfoZone.start({'opacity': [0, this.options.slideInfoZoneOpacity]});
        if (this.options.showCarousel)
            this.slideInfoZone.chain(this.centerCarouselOn.pass(this.currentIter, this));
        return this.slideInfoZone;
    },
    hideInfoSlideShow: function() {
        this.fireEvent('onHideInfopane');
        this.slideInfoZone.clearTimer();
        if(this.options.slideInfoZoneSlide)
            this.slideInfoZone.start({'opacity': 0, 'height': 0});
        else
            this.slideInfoZone.start({'opacity': 0});
        return this.slideInfoZone;
    },
    makeLink: function(num) {
        this.currentLink.setProperties({
            href: this.galleryData[num].link,
            title: this.galleryData[num].linkTitle
        })
        if (!((this.options.embedLinks) && (!this.options.showArrows) && (!this.options.showCarousel)))
            this.currentLink.setStyle('display', 'block');
    },
    clearLink: function() {
        this.currentLink.setProperties({href: '', title: ''});
        if (!((this.options.embedLinks) && (!this.options.showArrows) && (!this.options.showCarousel)))
            this.currentLink.setStyle('display', 'none');
    },
    /* To change the gallery data, those two functions : */
    flushGallery: function() {
        this.galleryElements.each(function(myFx) {
            myFx.element.remove();
            myFx = myFx.element = null;
        });
        this.galleryElements = [];
    },
    changeData: function(data) {
        this.galleryData = data;
        this.clearTimer();
        this.flushGallery();
        if (this.options.showCarousel) this.flushCarousel();
        this.constructElements();
        if (this.options.showCarousel) this.fillCarousel();
        if (this.options.showInfopane) this.hideInfoSlideShow();
        this.galleryInit=1;
        this.lastIter=0;
        this.currentIter=0;
        this.doSlideShow(1);
    },
    /* Plugins: HistoryManager */
    initHistory: function() {
        this.fireEvent('onHistoryInit');
        this.historyKey = this.galleryElement.id + '-picture';
        if (this.options.customHistoryKey)
            this.historyKey = this.options.customHistoryKey();
        this.history = HistoryManager.register(
            this.historyKey,
            [1],
            function(values) {
                if (parseInt(values[0])-1 < this.maxIter)
                    this.goTo(parseInt(values[0])-1);
            }.bind(this),
            function(values) {
                return [this.historyKey, '(', values[0], ')'].join('');
            }.bind(this),
            this.historyKey + '\\((\\d+)\\)');
        this.addEvent('onChanged', function(){
            this.history.setValue(0, this.currentIter+1);
        }.bind(this));
        this.fireEvent('onHistoryInited');
    }
};
gallery = new Class(gallery);
gallery.implement(new Events);
gallery.implement(new Options);

gallery.Transitions = new Abstract ({
    fade: function(oldFx, newFx, oldPos, newPos){
        oldFx.options.transition = newFx.options.transition = Fx.Transitions.linear;
        oldFx.options.duration = newFx.options.duration = this.options.fadeDuration;
        if (newPos > oldPos) newFx.start({opacity: 1});
        else
        {
            newFx.set({opacity: 1});
            oldFx.start({opacity: 0});
        }
    },
    crossfade: function(oldFx, newFx, oldPos, newPos){
        oldFx.options.transition = newFx.options.transition = Fx.Transitions.linear;
        oldFx.options.duration = newFx.options.duration = this.options.fadeDuration;
        newFx.start({opacity: 1});
        oldFx.start({opacity: 0});
    },
    fadebg: function(oldFx, newFx, oldPos, newPos){
        oldFx.options.transition = newFx.options.transition = Fx.Transitions.linear;
        oldFx.options.duration = newFx.options.duration = this.options.fadeDuration / 2;
        oldFx.start({opacity: 0}).chain(newFx.start.pass([{opacity: 1}], newFx));
    }
});

/* All code copyright 2007 Jonathan Schemoul */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Follows: Preloader (class)
 * Simple class for preloading images with support for progress reporting
 * Copyright 2007 Tomocchino.
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

var Preloader = new Class({

  Implements: [Events, Options],

  options: {
    root        : '',
    period      : 100
  },

  initialize: function(options){
    this.setOptions(options);
  },

  load: function(sources) {
    this.index = 0;
    this.images = [];
    this.sources = this.temps = sources;
    this.total = this. sources.length;

    this.fireEvent('onStart', [this.index, this.total]);
    this.timer = this.progress.periodical(this.options.period, this);

    this.sources.each(function(source, index){
      this.images[index] = new Asset.image(this.options.root + source, {
        'onload'  : function(){ this.index++; if(this.images[index]) this.fireEvent('onLoad', [this.images[index], index, source]); }.bind(this),
        'onerror' : function(){ this.index++; this.fireEvent('onError', [this.images.splice(index, 1), index, source]); }.bind(this),
        'onabort' : function(){ this.index++; this.fireEvent('onError', [this.images.splice(index, 1), index, source]); }.bind(this)
      });
    }, this);
  },

  progress: function() {
    this.fireEvent('onProgress', [Math.min(this.index, this.total), this.total]);
    if(this.index >= this.total) this.complete();
  },

  complete: function(){
    $clear(this.timer);
    this.fireEvent('onComplete', [this.images]);
  },

  cancel: function(){
    $clear(this.timer);
  }

});

Preloader.implement(new Events, new Options);

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Follows: formatString (function)
 * Original name: Yahoo.Tools.printf
 * Copyright Yahoo.
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

function formatString() {
    var num = arguments.length;
    var oStr = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        var pattern = "\\{" + (i-1) + "\\}"; 
        var re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
        oStr = oStr.replace(re, arguments[i]);
    }
    return oStr; 
}
```

Comment: That slideshow is based on Mootools, so are you using Mootools or jQuery?

Comment: You should post some sample code of what you already have. Its easier to work with that then creating an example for you from scratch.

Comment: **Why** have you put the jQuery tag on a post about Mootools?

Comment: People nowdays use jQuery and JavaScript interchangeably.  It's part of dumbing down our society.

Comment: I can't believe you posted the whole js file.  Please will you make a jsfiddle?  www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Gallery instance variable is "myGallery"

```
var theGalleryElement = $('myGallery');

var myGallery = new gallery( theGalleryElement ,{... some options ...}); // from his site

theGalleryElement.addEvents({
  'mouseenter':function(){
     myGallery.clearTimer();
  },
  'mouseleave':function(){
    myGallery.prepareTimer();
  }
});
```